# Is variance continuous for Gaussian martingale with continuous paths?

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, stochastic-processes

Let $X: [0, \infty) \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Gaussian process, I.e. all $X_t$ lie in the same Gaussian space, a closed sub space of $L^2(\Omega)$ containing  only Gaussian random variables.  Assume $X$ also has continuous sample paths and $X_0=0$.  Is this enough to conclude that the function $f: t\mapsto var(X_t)$ is continuous? What if X is also assumed to be a martingale?  The reason I ask is I’m asked to prove that that under these conditions, $f: t\mapsto var(X_t)$ is the quadratic variation of $X$.  I can prove that $f$ is nondecreasing and that $X^2_t-f(t)$ is a martingale, but I need to show $f$ is continuous.  If pointwise convergence in a Gaussian space implied L^2 convergence, that would do it, but of course that is stronger than what I need.

Comment: I would be curious to see your proof that $f$ is nondecreasing.  I don't think it is in general.

Comment: @user6247850 for t<s, using martingale property we can get $E[X_s^2-X_t^2]=E[(X_s-X_t)^2]$. Lmk if it’s unclear

Comment: Isn't L² continuity actually exactly what you need, because of the Riesz-Scheffé lemma?

Comment: @Noam Ah, sorry, I missed that this was in the case that $X$ was assumed to be a martingale.

Comment: @nejimban You’re saying it’s not true in this generality? Or you’re just saying L^2 continuity isn’t strictly stronger?

Comment: @Noam that it isn't strictly stronger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $X$ is a martingale, we have $\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \mathbb{E}[X_0] = 0$.  Since each $X_t$ is Gaussian, $\mathbb{E}[X_t^4] = 3 \mathbb{E}[X_t^2]^2 = 3 f(t)^2 \le 3 f(T)^2$ where $T > t$.  This implies $(X_t^2)_{t \in [0,T]}$ is a uniformly integrable set of random variables, and therefore $$\lim_{s \rightarrow t} f(s) = \lim_{s \rightarrow t} \mathbb{E}[X_s^2] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \lim_{s \rightarrow t} X_s^2 \right] = \mathbb{E}[X_t^2] = f(t)$$
so we conclude $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Oooooo very nice